# Trying to repair or eliminate "Written by" author field in article view

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, css, layout

I'm trying to figure out where in the heck is the "*Written by*" tagline displayed at the top of each news article...basically, which css/php/whatever file holds the layout for articles and would contain that.  Somehow the name of the article's author isn't showing up next to "Written by," and I'm trying to find out why.  I've tried a couple of things already:

1)  Switching the global "Show/Hide Author" option does NOT work:  there is absolutely no change in the "Written by" text, and the author's name is still blank.  It also doesn't work in the **Article** options menu either.

2)  I tried searching for the configuration/template file on Google...a couple of articles mentioned a *content.html.php* file in the *com_content* folder, but I suspect that must have been for an earlier version of Joomla, as I don't have that file (I'm using 3.x).  As of now, I don't know whether it's a css file, php file, or something else.

3)  I tried to do a search on the source code in my site folder using "Written by," but I only came up with two language **.ini** files.  Taking the "Written by" text out of those didn't change anything, either.  I also tried "author"...nothing of any substance resulted.  I don't know of any other variable name or text to key in on.

I *think* I may have altered something in the past and that's why the author name is not showing up beside the "Written by," but I can't be sure.  Besides, doing a "Hide" on the Global options should have taken care of what's left, regardless.  I'm pretty much at my wits' end.  Can anyone help me with this?

THANKS!

UPDATE:  I **FINALLY** was able to make the "Written by" text disappear (it was an option on the *menu* setting...Joomla seems counter-intuitive at times).  However, I'm still at a loss regarding why the author's name doesn't show up next to the "Written by."

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer so you can accept it and resolve this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show or hide author you dont have to hack the core files as there are predefined option in the administrator panel. Login to Administrator and click on Content article. You will find option on top right; click on that. You will find several options to display article.
[image]

Comment: Hello @Amit_Ray...thanks for your suggestion!  However, as I mentioned above, I already tried changing the Global options for showing/hiding author, but it had no effect, and I don't understand why that's the case.  That's partially why I wanted to find out which core file(s) control the author being displayed, to see if there were any modifications done that disabled it there.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your template has a template override for that view (single article or category blog)?  I would go to templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_content/article and templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_content/category, backup the files there, and then delete.  Check to see if it functions normally without those.

Answer (score 0):

add %s to the written by like this: written by %s

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing. 
 Please be more generous when sharing your insights.  Endeavour to educate/empower thousands of future researchers when you post an answer.  Including links to documentation/tutorials is a great way to support your advice.  Please consider editing your answer to expand your advice.  Please also take the [tour].